# Bash script pipe barrier

Tags: bash, pipe, buffer, barrier, bash-trap

My current script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap flush_buffer SIGUSR1

flush_buffer() {
    echo "flushing buffer" >&2
    [ -n "$buffer" ] && echo -e "$buffer"
    buffer=""
}

trap exit_script INT TERM

exit_script() {
    echo "script shutting down" >&2
    flush_buffer()
}

while read -r line; do
    [ -z "$buffer" ] && buffer="$line" || buffer="$buffer\n$line"
done
```

There are test cases like this:

`$(echo  "ad-hoc run the script" | ./pipe-barrier.sh 2> /dev/null) == "ad-hoc run the script"`

But this is not even working too.

And does this code behave the following cases correctly?

- blank input
- large amounts of input between the buffer flushes
- simultaneous execution (multiple instances of the script run simultaneously)

Thanks for help :)

UPDATE

```
#!/bin/bash

trap flush_buffer USR1

flush_buffer() {
    echo "flushing buffer" >&2
    [ -n "$buffer" ] && echo -e "$buffer"
    buffer=""
}

trap exit_script EXIT

exit_script() {
    echo "script shutting down" >&2
    flush_buffer
    exit 0
}

while read -r line; do
    [ -z "$buffer" ] && buffer="$line" || buffer="$buffer\n$line"
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple problems in your script... dropping `2> /dev/null` from your test wold be provide you with useful hint to spot:

```
    flush_buffer()
```

Function call should be

```
    flush_buffer
```

Also, the other problem is. When you run out of input, you just exit the script, but never flush your buffer... either add `flush_buffer` past the `while` loop to call it in that case... or also set use it as a handler setting trap on `EXIT`.

---

I can just as well update this I reckon: Your update... there is still one other problem... if you handle the `INT` and `TERM` signals, you return control back to where the trap was set off (very likely the `while` loop): You want to explicitly `exit` from `exit_script`.

Also as per docs:

> A trap on `EXIT` is executed before the shell terminates.

So... you really only set a trap on `EXIT`... otherwise in case of being tripped by `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`, you'd call it (and flush) twice. Once to on the two signals... and then second time with an empty `buffer` on exiting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I updated my original post, is it correctly behaving like that?

Comment: Not entirely... Your handler handles, but does not `exit` the script, so it returns back to the `read` loop in case of `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT`. So you need to explicitly exit from the `exit_script`. Also... those signals will cause the shell to terminate (trip `EXIT` as well) and you do not want to run the same handler twice, so just `trap`ing `EXIT` is really what you want.

Comment: So you mean I only need to trap EXIT instead of INT and TERM? If it's correct, then I should add `exit 1` to the handler to exit the script after flushing the buffer?

Comment: I've written it above, that should make it clearer... I'd `exit 0` unless you consider any of the scenarios abnormal termination (which it does not sound to be the spec).

Comment: I've updated my first post again with the corrections

Comment: That should take care of the obvious "not working" that comes to mind... Try it out?

Comment: All the public tests are working now, but I am not sure about this section `"Treat the following marginal cases correctly"`

Comment: Not sure how else blank input could look, but it does not break and just flushes empty buffer. Running these in parallel should not be a problem. Large amount of data... depends on how large (>=128kB would likely land you in trouble).